# How can I debug Tridion Templates locally without connecting to TcmTemplateDebugHost?

Tags: 2011, 2013, templating

Everyone might be facing the same problem with debugging Tridion templates: How to debug Tridion Templates locally without connecting to the remote `TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe`

> **Is there way to debug Tridion templates locally?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to debug tridion templates locally.

**@Rob** has provided a wonderful facility called the **"TcmDebugger"** which enables the ability to debug templates locally without connecting to a remote `TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe`.

### What is TcmDebugger?

**TcmDebugger** is a .NET console application which runs the SDL Tridion Content Manager render/publishing engine in a local context.

This allows a developer to extensively debug .NET templates, .NET custom functionsources and .NET custom mediators on their local workstation.

**[SDL Tridion Content Manager .NET Templating Debugger](https://code.google.com/p/tcmdebugger/)**

With this TCMDebugger, we can test the template in three engine types that is **Debug**, **Debug Engine Server** and **Render** engines

Comment: This does mean you need to give the developer direct database access, by supplying your database username and password and opening the database firewall up to the developer directly. Not really good in terms of security, and I doubt it would be allowed by many customers, but nice attempt...

Comment: @BartKoopman: Developer required database access with **Read Only** permission (which is one time setup and same username and password will be used across multiple developers). Now multiple developers can debug their templates at a time with no dependency on connecting to remote or having local installation or local admin rights or remote access.

Comment: @BartKoopman: Rather than giving a developer with remote user access, giving a developer database access with **Read Only** permission is more safe. :)

Comment: SDL Tridion Content Manager .NET Templating Debugger link is dead.
Did the code get moved to another repo?

Answer (score 5):

To execute a template you need to run it on the server, as it needs to have a database connection to the CM database to pull in all the content plus consituent TBBs, plus access to all of the Tridion API to know what to do with this. As such it is not possible (at present) to execute a template (and thus also to debug them) locally without connecting to the server

Comment: Yes it was. But `Rob` has given a provision to debug locally.

Comment: Haha - yes just saw your answer! That looks useful