# How to debug with template builder

Tags: 2009

I'm getting started with tridion and i'm working on an "old" tridion project.
With the template builder, i managed to see how the component models are built but i need to debug my C# code which is inside a block of construction of model (not sure about the translation in english, sorry).

How can i see when i debug with the template builder what a variable contains?
Thanks in advance for your help.

For example, in the following code , i want for instance to see what "publicationTitle" contains:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields" %>
log.Debug("Begin: GroupDocumentItems");

string publicationTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(package.GetValue("Page.Publication.Title")) ? package.GetValue("Component.Publication.Title") : package.GetValue("Page.Publication.Title");
package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text,publicationTitle);
Component comp = engine.GetSession().GetObject(package.GetValue("Component.ID")) as Component;
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(comp.Content, comp.Schema);
TextField field = fields["pathFolder"] as TextField;
string location = field.Value;

List<TcmUri> list = new List<TcmUri>();

Filter componentFilter = new Filter();
componentFilter.Conditions.Add("Recursive", true);
componentFilter.Conditions.Add("ItemType", ItemType.Component);
OrganizationalItem oi = engine.GetSession().GetObject("/webdav/" + publicationTitle + location) as OrganizationalItem;
foreach (Component siblingComponent in oi.GetItems(componentFilter))
{
    if (siblingComponent.Schema.Title == "SC_document")
    {
        list.Add (new TcmUri(siblingComponent.Id));
    }
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<root>");           
sb.Append("<items>");
foreach (TcmUri tu in list)
{
    sb.Append("$(tfde:" + tu.ToString() + ";Document Item XML)");
}
sb.Append("</items>");
sb.Append("</root>");
package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, sb.ToString()));
log.Debug("End: GroupDocumentItems");
```

And if possible, i would like to see it in the output tab in the template builder when i debug my component model under a specific component.

Comment: Hello, welcome FieryA and thanks for asking on Tridion Stack Exchange. If you're looking for values _in_ Template Builder, that would be in the Package, which updates after each TBB "runs." Or are you looking for variables from your C# code (which you could also add to the Template Builder Package)?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Maybe it's more clear for you now.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it seems i managed to make it work with 
package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text,publicationTitle);

it appears in a tab while debugging.
Is it the only way to debug ? Thanks !

Comment: So if you see "End: GroupDocuemntItems" in the debug window ... why not try         log.Debug("value of sb: ")     -and-     log.Debug(sb.ToString())

Comment: Indeed, it seems a log framework like log.net was implemented but i didn't find where the log file is located in the server yet ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to debug a C# fragment building block. This is not going to work. (It's probably possible, but only as an exercise in esoteric intransigence.) It should be straightforward enough to copy and paste the code into Visual Studio and build it into proper assembly templates that you can debug.

Once you've done that, make a fresh debug build, upload it to Tridion with debug symbols, and attach a debugger in the standard way.

Answer (score 6):

Did you read these

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210711/tridion-template-builder-and-visual-studio-debugging
- [How can I debug Tridion Templates locally without connecting to TcmTemplateDebugHost?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/how-can-i-debug-tridion-templates-locally-without-connecting-to-tcmtemplatedebug)
- http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-05CAD6E3-2CC0-4846-AB72-0F062A07C844

If you did - but they didn't suit then perhaps you can expand on what you have tried, what problems you encountered and what the technical setup is.

Comment: The links you have posted didn't help i think.

 
I have updated my answer. Maybe it's more clear for you now. Thanks for your help